# What does it mean when there is a strikeout on my username on a comment discussion?

Tags: discussion, design, comment-flags

Today, I took part on a comment discussion on English SE site and I saw my username being striked-out like this:

[image]

What does that mean? Am I being flagged or marked in any particular manner? Here is the link to the comment:

[Whats wrong in using the words Whilst and Due to?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/231885/whats-wrong-in-using-the-words-whilst-and-due-to?noredirect=1#comment497229_231885)

Comment: No worries, it's just a design bug related to you being the owner of the question. The `.owner` is using the extra sprite image in the background and doing an awful job of it.

Comment: @TimStone that's very disappointing to hear. I was hoping for something more... entertaining. Like, _this is a sign that some moderator is angry at you and that you are at risk of being suspended..._

Comment: It means that (some part of) your writing style is outmoded and will be officially deprecated when English 17.9.0 is rolled out to the world at large. Any day now….